# How to alter the menu overview?

Tags: forms, theming

I was trying to add another additional column in the menu overview (admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu). I used the following code:

```
function mymod_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'menu_overview_form') {
        foreach ($form as $key => $item) {
            if (is_array($item) && isset($item['#item'])) {
                $item['node_url'] = array(
                    '#markup' => 'foobar'
                );

            }
        }
    }
}
```

It actually adds the indexes but the render output is not changed. How can I add an additional column to that overview?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think you should look at `hook_menu_alter()`
please Visit:https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7